# Why is twitter bootstrap carousel class "slide" unknown in bootsrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded the twitter bootsrap carousel example. I noticed that when I navigate the slide nothing happens and in my view the "slide" class from the bootstrap.css version 3 is unknown.

Based on the `head` section below I believe I have all the necessary js and css files.

I have 2 questions. Why is the the "slide" class unknown and should the carousel be navigable straight out of the box?

```
<head>
<link href ="/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href ="/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Content/bootstrap/js-twitter-bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>

        <script  data-main="/Scripts/main" src="~/Scripts/require.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
</div
```

Comment: Where is your `<body>` element? And why are you linking a style sheet via a `<script>` element?

Comment: Thats a mistake. Let me correct

Comment: The carousel is in the body element I just did not add it but I fix the css . slide is still unknown

Comment: I manually searched for a slide class in the css and its not there

Comment: It looks like the "slide" class is only there for the purposes of the Javascript - if you look at the [example page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) there are no styles being applied for the "slide" class.

Comment: OK thanks . That explains it. But the slide should be navigable. right?

Comment: I think I am ok now. I just need items in the caption

Comment: It would appear  that 'slide' designated within the class property isn't referencing  a CSS class at all; but is a call to a  function in bootstrap.js which gives the carousel controls (left, right) their proper functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code for carousel,

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
   <div class="container">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64," data-src="holder.js/100%x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:First slide" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Slide 1.</h1>

          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64," data-src="holder.js/100%x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Slide 2</h1>

          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64," data-src="holder.js/100%x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Slide 3</h1>

          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
<script src="../../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/js/holder.js"></script>
```